# Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-faq

I am trying to make a bar graph where the largest bar would be nearest to the y axis and the shortest bar would be furthest. So this is kind of like the Table I have

```
    Name   Position
1   James  Goalkeeper
2   Frank  Goalkeeper
3   Jean   Defense
4   Steve  Defense
5   John   Defense
6   Tim    Striker
```

So I am trying to build a bar graph that would show the number of players according to position

```
p <- ggplot(theTable, aes(x = Position)) + geom_bar(binwidth = 1)
```

but the graph shows the goalkeeper bar first then the defense, and finally the striker one. I would want the graph to be ordered so that the defense bar is closest to the y axis, the goalkeeper one, and finally the striker one.
Thanks

Comment: can't ggplot reorder them for you without having to mess around with the table (or dataframe)?

Comment: @MattO'Brien I find it incredible that this is not done in a single, simple command

Comment: @Zimano Too bad that's what you're getting from my comment. My observation was towards the creators of `ggplot2`, not the OP

Comment: @Euler_Salter Thank you for clarifying, my sincere apologies for jumping on you like that. I have deleted my original remark.

Comment: ggplot2 currently ignores `binwidth = 1` with a warning. To control the width of the bars (and have no gaps between bars), you might want to use `width = 1` instead.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

The key with ordering is to set the levels of the factor in the order you want. An ordered factor is not required; the extra information in an ordered factor isn't necessary and if these data are being used in any statistical model, the wrong parametrisation might result — polynomial contrasts aren't right for nominal data such as this.

```
## set the levels in order we want
theTable <- within(theTable, 
                   Position <- factor(Position, 
                                      levels=names(sort(table(Position), 
                                                        decreasing=TRUE))))
## plot
ggplot(theTable,aes(x=Position))+geom_bar(binwidth=1)
```

[image: barplot figure]

In the most general sense, we simply need to set the factor levels to be in the desired order. If left unspecified, the levels of a factor will be sorted alphabetically. You can also specify the level order within the call to factor as above, and other ways are possible as well.

```
theTable$Position <- factor(theTable$Position, levels = c(...))
```

Comment: @Gavin: 2 simplifications: since you already are using `within`, there's no need to use `theTable$Position`, and you could just do `sort(-table(...))` for decreasing order.

Comment: @Prasad the former was a leftover from testing so thanks for pointing that out. As far the latter, I prefer explicitly asking for the reversed sort than the `-` you use as it is far easier to get the intention from `decreasing = TRUE` than noticing the `-` in all the rest of the code.

Comment: @Gavin ok I see what you mean

Comment: @Prasad - it it just personal preference after many years writing analysis scripts in my work that I have had to revisit at times and cursed myself for not writing clearer code. There is nothing wrong with using `-`.

Comment: @Gavin, sure your approach makes sense. I frequently choose shorter syntax over clarity but I know it can come back to bite me sometimes!

Comment: `geom_bar()` no longer has a `binwidth` parameter. Please use `geom_histogram()` instead.

Comment: @GavinSimpson; I think the part about `levels(theTable$Position) <- c(...)` leads to undesired behaviour where the actual entries of the data frame gets reordered, and not just the levels of the factor. See
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-factor-without-changing-order-of-values). Maybe you should modify or remove those lines?

Comment: Strongly agree with Anton. I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54756565/903061) and went poking around on where they got the bad advice to use `levels<-`. I'm going to edit that part out, at least tentatively.

Comment: @Anton Thanks for the suggestion (and to Gregor for the edit); I would never do this via `levels<-()` today. This is something from from 8 years back and I can't recall if things were different back then or whether I was just plain wrong, but regardless, it is wrong and should be erased! Thanks!

Answer (score 274):

@GavinSimpson: `reorder` is a powerful and effective solution for this:

```
ggplot(theTable,
       aes(x=reorder(Position,Position,
                     function(x)-length(x)))) +
       geom_bar()
```

Comment: Indeed +1, and especially in this case where there is a logical order that we can exploit numerically. If we consider arbitrary ordering of categories and we don't want alphabetical then it is just as easy (easier?) to specify the levels directly as shown.

Comment: This is the neatest. Nullify the need to modify original dataframe

Comment: Lovely, just noticed that you can do this a little more succincly, if all you want is to order by the length function and ascending order is okay, which is something I often want to do: `ggplot(theTable,aes(x=reorder(Position,Position,length))+geom_bar()`

Answer (score 206):

Using `scale_x_discrete (limits = ...)` to specify the order of bars.

```
positions <- c("Goalkeeper", "Defense", "Striker")
p <- ggplot(theTable, aes(x = Position)) + scale_x_discrete(limits = positions)
```

Comment: Your solution is the most suitable to my situation, as I want to program to plot with x being an arbitrary column expressed by a variable in a data.frame. The other suggestions would be harder to express the arrangement of the order of x by an expression involving the variable. Thanks!  If there is interest, I can share my solution using your suggestion. Just one more issue, adding scale_x_discrete(limits = ...), I found that there is blank space as wide as the bar-chart, on the right of the chart. How can I get rid of the blank space? As it does not serve any purpose.

Comment: This seems necessary for ordering histogram bars

Comment: QIBIN: Wow...the other answers here work, but your answer by far seems not just the most concise and elegant, but the most obvious when thinking from within ggplot's framework. Thank you.

Comment: When I tried this solution, on my data it, didn't graph NAs. Is there a way to use this solution and have it graph NAs?

Comment: This solution worked for me where the others above did not.

Answer (score 109):

I think the already provided solutions are overly verbose. A more concise way to do a frequency sorted barplot with ggplot is

```
ggplot(theTable, aes(x=reorder(Position, -table(Position)[Position]))) + geom_bar()
```

It's similar to what Alex Brown suggested, but a bit shorter and works without an anynymous function definition.

**Update**

I think my old solution was good at the time, but nowadays I'd rather use `forcats::fct_infreq` which is sorting factor levels by frequency:

```
require(forcats)

ggplot(theTable, aes(fct_infreq(Position))) + geom_bar()
```

Comment: I do not understand the second argument to reorder function and what does it do. Can you kindly explain what is happening?

Comment: @user3282777 have you tried the docs https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/reorder.factor.html ?

Comment: Great solution!  Good to see others employing tidyverse solutions!

Answer (score 42):

Like `reorder()` in Alex Brown's answer, we could also use `forcats::fct_reorder()`. It will basically sort the factors specified in the 1st arg, according to the values in the 2nd arg after applying a specified function (default = median, which is what we use here as just have one value per factor level).

It is a shame that in the OP's question, the order required is also alphabetical as that is the default sort order when you create factors, so will hide what this function is actually doing. To make it more clear, I'll replace "Goalkeeper" with "Zoalkeeper".

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)

theTable <- data.frame(
                Name = c('James', 'Frank', 'Jean', 'Steve', 'John', 'Tim'),
                Position = c('Zoalkeeper', 'Zoalkeeper', 'Defense',
                             'Defense', 'Defense', 'Striker'))

theTable %>%
    count(Position) %>%
    mutate(Position = fct_reorder(Position, n, .desc = TRUE)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Position, y = n)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO best solution as forcats is as well as dplyr a tidyverse package.

Comment: thumbs up for Zoalkeeper

Answer (score 33):

Another alternative using **reorder** to order the levels of a factor. In ascending (n) or descending order (-n) based on the count. Very similar to the one using `fct_reorder` from the `forcats` package:

Descending order

```
df %>%
  count(Position) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Position, -n), y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  xlab("Position")
```

[image]

Ascending order

```
df %>%
  count(Position) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Position, n), y = n)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  xlab("Position")
```

[image]

Data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(Position = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Defense", 
"Striker", "Zoalkeeper"), class = "factor"), Name = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("Frank", "James", "Jean", "John", 
"Steve", "Tim"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: adding count before hand i think is the simplest approach

Answer (score 29):

A simple dplyr based reordering of factors can solve this problem:

```
library(dplyr)

#reorder the table and reset the factor to that ordering
theTable %>%
  group_by(Position) %>%                              # calculate the counts
  summarize(counts = n()) %>%
  arrange(-counts) %>%                                # sort by counts
  mutate(Position = factor(Position, Position)) %>%   # reset factor
  ggplot(aes(x=Position, y=counts)) +                 # plot 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")                         # plot histogram
```

Answer (score 21):

In addition to `forcats::fct_infreq`, mentioned by
@HolgerBrandl, there is `forcats::fct_rev`, which reverses the factor order.

```
theTable <- data.frame(
    Position= 
        c("Zoalkeeper", "Zoalkeeper", "Defense",
          "Defense", "Defense", "Striker"),
    Name=c("James", "Frank","Jean",
           "Steve","John", "Tim"))

p1 <- ggplot(theTable, aes(x = Position)) + geom_bar()
p2 <- ggplot(theTable, aes(x = fct_infreq(Position))) + geom_bar()
p3 <- ggplot(theTable, aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(Position)))) + geom_bar()

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, nrow=3)
```

[image]

Comment: "fct_infreq(Position)" is the little thing that does so much, thanks!!

Answer (score 20):

You just need to specify the `Position` column to be an *ordered factor* where the levels are ordered by their counts:

```
theTable <- transform( theTable,
       Position = ordered(Position, levels = names( sort(-table(Position)))))
```

(Note that the `table(Position)` produces a frequency-count of the `Position` column.)

Then your `ggplot` function will show the bars in decreasing order of count.
I don't know if there's an option in `geom_bar` to do this without having to explicitly create an ordered factor.

Comment: I didn't fully parse your code up there, but I'm pretty sure `reorder()` from the stats library accomplishes the same task.

Comment: @Chase how do you propose using `reorder()` in this case? The factor requiring reordering needs to be reordered by some function of itself and I'm struggling to see a good way to do that.

Comment: ok, `with(theTable, reorder(Position, as.character(Position), function(x) sum(duplicated(x))))` is one way, and another `with(theTable, reorder(Position, as.character(Position), function(x) as.numeric(table(x))))` but these are just as convoluted...

Comment: I simplified the answer slightly to use `sort` rather than `order`

Comment: @Gavin - perhaps I misunderstood Prasad's original code (I don't have R on this machine to test...) but it looked as if he was reordering the categories based on frequency, which `reorder` is adept at doing. I agree for this question that something more involved is needed. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This does proposal not work with the data set provided in my other comments today.

Answer (score 14):

If the chart columns come from a numeric variable as in the dataframe below, you can use a simpler solution:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(Colors, -Qty, sum), y = Qty)) 
+ geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

The minus sign before the sort variable (-Qty) controls the sort direction (ascending/descending)

Here's some data for testing:

```
df <- data.frame(Colors = c("Green","Yellow","Blue","Red","Yellow","Blue"),  
                 Qty = c(7,4,5,1,3,6)
                )

**Sample data:**
  Colors Qty
1  Green   7
2 Yellow   4
3   Blue   5
4    Red   1
5 Yellow   3
6   Blue   6
```

When I found this thread, that was the answer I was looking for. Hope it's useful for others.

Answer (score 13):

I agree with zach that counting within dplyr is the best solution. I've found this to be the shortest version:

```
dplyr::count(theTable, Position) %>%
          arrange(-n) %>%
          mutate(Position = factor(Position, Position)) %>%
          ggplot(aes(x=Position, y=n)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

This will also be significantly faster than reordering the factor levels beforehand since the count is done in dplyr not in ggplot or using `table`.

Answer (score 12):

I found it very annoying that `ggplot2` doesn't offer an 'automatic' solution for this. That's why I created the `bar_chart()` function in [`ggcharts`](https://thomas-neitmann.github.io/ggcharts/index.html).

```r
ggcharts::bar_chart(theTable, Position)
```

[image]

By default `bar_chart()` sorts the bars and displays a horizontal plot. To change that set  `horizontal = FALSE`. In addition, `bar_chart()` removes the unsightly 'gap' between the bars and the axis.

Answer (score 3):

Since we are only looking at the distribution of a *single variable* ("Position") as opposed to looking at the relationship between *two variables*, then perhaps a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) would be the more appropriate graph. ggplot has [geom_histogram()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) that makes it easy:

```
ggplot(theTable, aes(x = Position)) + geom_histogram(stat="count")
```

[image]

**Using geom_histogram():**

I think [geom_histogram(](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html)) is a little quirky as it treats continuous and discrete data differently.

For **continuous data**, you can just use [geom_histogram()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html) with no parameters.
For example, if we add in a numeric vector "Score"...

```
    Name   Position   Score  
1   James  Goalkeeper 10
2   Frank  Goalkeeper 20
3   Jean   Defense    10
4   Steve  Defense    10
5   John   Defense    20
6   Tim    Striker    50
```

and use geom_histogram() on the "Score" variable...

```
ggplot(theTable, aes(x = Score)) + geom_histogram()
```

[image]

For **discrete data** like "Position" we have to specify a calculated statistic computed by the aesthetic to give the y value for the height of the bars using `stat = "count"`:

```
 ggplot(theTable, aes(x = Position)) + geom_histogram(stat = "count")
```

**Note:** Curiously and confusingly you can also use `stat = "count"` for continuous data as well and I think it provides a more aesthetically pleasing graph.

```
ggplot(theTable, aes(x = Score)) + geom_histogram(stat = "count")
```

[image]

**Edits**: Extended answer in response to [DebanjanB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7429447/debanjanb)'s helpful suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure why this solution is mentioned, as your first example is exactly equivalent to `ggplot(theTable, aes(x = Position)) + geom_bar()` (i.e., with the current version 3.3.2 of ggplot2, the order is alphabetical for a char variable, or respects the factor order if it is an ordered factor).
Or maybe there _used_ to be a difference?

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

dd <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Name,    ~Position,
  "James", "Goalkeeper",
  "Frank", "Goalkeeper",
   "Jean",    "Defense",
   "John",    "Defense",
  "Steve",    "Defense",
    "Tim",    "Striker"
  )


dd %>% ggplot(aes(x = forcats::fct_infreq(Position))) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `ggplot2`, there is also [ggpubr](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/ggpubr/) with a really helpful argument for the `ggbarplot` function. You can sort the bars by `sort.val` in "desc" and "asc" like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggpubr)
# desc
df %>%
  count(Position) %>%
  ggbarplot(x = "Position", 
            y = "n",
            sort.val = "desc")
```

[image]

```r
# asc
df %>%
  count(Position) %>%
  ggbarplot(x = "Position", 
            y = "n",
            sort.val = "asc")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

As you can see, it is really simple to sort the bars. This can also be done if the bars are grouped. Check the link above for some helpful examples.

Answer (score -2):

you can simply use this code:

```
ggplot(yourdatasetname, aes(Position, fill = Name)) + 
     geom_bar(col = "black", size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to contain an explanation?