# Sorting data on X axis

Tags: r, sorting

I have created a plot of coverage vs gene. I would like to plot the genes (x axis) from lowest coverage value (y axis) to largest. I used the function "plot" but it automatically sorts the gene names from lowest to highest. How do I arrange them from lowest coverage to highest instead?

Comment: Your question seems to be answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-data-frame-without-changing-order-of-values

Comment: If you use ggplot2 it's probably necessary to make the names an ordered factor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe switch the `ylim`:

```
plot(1:10, ylim=c(10,1))
```