# Revisit the ordering in factor

Tags: r

I have read the SO thread: 
[Reorder levels of a factor without changing order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-data-frame-without-changing-order-of-values), which works fine. However, on the particular use case, I am puzzled on the output:

```
> df$mode
[1]  write               read                write_with_journal  write               read                write_with_journal
[7]  write               read                write_with_journal
Levels:  read  write  write_with_journal
```

Now, I am changing the factor order from "`read write write_with_journal`" to `"write read write_with_journal`":

```
> factor(df$mode, levels = c('write', 'read', 'write_with_journal'))
[1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: write read write_with_journal
```

Notice all the previous category values "write", "read" etc. are replaced with NA. 
I am not sure why this is happening. If I manually create the data frame (instead of reading from a file) as the following:

```
> p = factor(rep(c("write", "read", "write_with_journal"),3))
> factor(p, levels = c('write', 'read', 'write_with_journal'))
```

Then everything is fine. Why?

Comment: Try `factor(as.character(df$mode), levels = c('write', 'read', 'write_with_journal'))`.

Comment: Not sure why this question is down flagged. I'd appreciate it if you care to explain so I could improve future questions. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have training spaces in all the factor levels. Do this:

```
df$mode <- factor( gsub(" ", "", df$mode), 
                   levels = c('write', 'read', 'write_with_journal'))
```

Alternately (but not correcting the problem) you could do this:

```
df$mode <- factor( df$mode, 
                   levels = levels(df$mode)[c(2,1,3)] )
```

Just to demonstrate this is plausible (although by no means definitely the problem since other none printing characters do exist):

```
> p = factor(rep(c("write ", "read ", "write_with_journal "),3))
>  factor(p, levels = c('write', 'read', 'write_with_journal'))
[1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
Levels: write read write_with_journal
```

Comment: wonderful, should have used "strip.white=TRUE" when I read in the file, my bad.