# ggplot2 change labels in a legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I want to change Labels in a Legend.

```
 spi<-read.csv("spill.csv",as.is=TRUE)
 attach(spi)
 spi$date<-as.Date(spi$date)
 str(spi)
 data.frame:   3184 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ data1: chr  "oil to asset" "oil to asset" "oil to asset" "oil to asset" ...
 $ date : Date, format: "2007-01-10" "2007-01-11" ...
 $ sp   : num  7.7 7.95 7.54 7.61 7.67 ...

cont1 <- ggplot(spi,aes(x=date,y=sp,linetype=data1))+geom_line() +
            expand_limits(max(spi$sp), y=c(0,80)) + 
            labs(x = "", y = "") + 
            scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,80,10)) +
            scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed","solid")) +  
            scale_x_date(breaks=datebreaks1, labels=date_format("%Y")) +
            ggtitle("Oil and Fianacial Market") +
            annotate("rect", xmin=as.Date("2008-01-02"), xmax=as.Date("2008-06-30"), 
                     ymin=-Inf, ymax=Inf, alpha=.1, fill="blue") +
            theme(legend.position="bottom") + labs(linetype='')
```

Then I want to changeing asset to oil and oil to asset.

How I can chahge?

`scale_fill_discrete(labels=c("oil to asset" ,"asset to oil"))`

This is not working.

Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to change the labels for your `linetype` legend?  You'll need to do that with a `linetype` scale such as `scale_linetype_manual` or `scale_linetype_discrete`, not a `fill` scale.

Comment: It would be time easier to help you if attached fully reproducible example. With random data or with a link to real data.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually same solution as @aosmith suggested - add right `breaks` (not `labels`) to your `scale_linetype_manual`.

```
scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed","solid"), breaks=c("oil to asset" ,"asset to oil"))
```

I also recommend you to make your `spi$data1` a factor via `spi$data1 <- factor(spi$data1)`. ggplot chooses factor ordering from `levels(some_factor_variable`. You may avoid specifying the `breaks` on every graph by changing factor levels ordering. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-data-frame-without-changing-order-of-values) is an example how to do it.