# R: reorder levels according to numeric vector with duplicate values

Tags: r, dplyr, factors

Reordering a data frame according to a vector (for instance for correct `ggplot2` plotting) has been up on SO several times, for instance in this nice thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-data-frame-without-changing-order-of-values). Yet, I cannot get this to work - perhaps because some values are dupliate (at least this is what R's warning is about). Toy example using dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)
set.seed(8)
df <- tbl_df(data.frame(
  v1 = rnorm(8),
  v2 = rep(rnorm(4),2),
  v3 = rep(sample(LETTERS[],4),2)))
```

`v1`is only here so that all columns may be different across. The levels of `v3` is now

```
levels(df$v3) 
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

I would like to reorder `v3` according to `v2`, which contains duplicate values.

```
df[order(df$v2),"v2"][[1]]
[1] -3.0110517 -3.0110517 -0.7597938 -0.7597938 -0.5931743 -0.5931743  0.2920499  0.2920499
```

How come this does not work? :

```
df %>%
  mutate(v3 = factor(v3, levels=df[order(df$v2),"v2"][[1]]))
```

UPDATE:
Nor does this work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(v3 = factor(v3, levels=unique(df[order(df$v2),"v2"][[1]])))
```

Gives:

```
           v1         v2 v3
1 -0.08458607 -3.0110517 NA
2  0.84040013 -0.5931743 NA
3 -0.46348277 -0.7597938 NA
4 -0.55083500  0.2920499 NA
5  0.73604043 -3.0110517 NA
6 -0.10788140 -0.5931743 NA
7 -0.17028915 -0.7597938 NA
8 -1.08833171  0.2920499 NA
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr: No (see my update)

Comment: You have `"v2"` in the `df[order…` but but I think you want that to be `v3` - try `unique(df[order(df$v2),"v3"][[1]])` But, if you want an ordered factor, you'll need to set `ordered=TRUE` in the `factor` call.

Comment: Thats a beauty! I did not notice that! If you put it a answer I will immediatley acceot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid the "duplicate" warnings and also create an ordered factor over `v3` (ordered by `v2`), you can do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(v3 = factor(v3, 
                     ordered=TRUE, 
                     levels=unique(df[order(df$v2),"v3"][[1]])))
```

Comment: I will mainly do this for `ggplot2`- would the ordered=T arg be a advantage/disadvantage for plotting?

Comment: That depends. Factor orders influence ggplot in many ways (axes and facets to name 2).