# Reproducing Excel Graphics with some annotations in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice, data-analysis, rgraph

I'm performing Descriptive analysis in Excel these days. But being a R learner i want to reproduce (approx.) the Excel graphics in R by using R's own coding, packages, etc. Here is an example of data:
[image: dummy data]

and Excel Graph is

[image: Excel output of above data]

Being a beginner at learning of R my question is pretty simple: "How to produce this excel graph in R by using base plotting, lattice or ggplot2 whichever is appealing?"
Any help would be highly appreciated!!!

Comment: this (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggthemes/docs/theme_excel) should help you started

Comment: Would you be able to post your data with a data set that is easy to read into R? Check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1) for suggestions how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a multi-part question depending upon which elements of the plot are important. Here is a method to reproduce this figure using `ggplot2`.

First, I create a reproducible dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
Group1 = factor(rep(c("A", "Fially", "AC"), each = 3),  
    levels = c("A", "Fially", "AC")),
Group2 = factor(c("B", "GGF", "Kp"), 
    levels = c(c("B", "GGF", "Kp"))),
Value = c(100, 5, 6, 200, 42, 21, 300, 80, 15)
)
```

Note that you will need to reorder your factors (see [Reorder levels of a factor without changing order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-factor-without-changing-order-of-values) for more help with this if you need it).

Second, I plot the data using `ggplot2` using a bar-plot (see the documentation [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html)).

```
library(ggplot2)
ggOut <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Group1, 
                y = Value, fill = Group2)) +
         geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") +
         theme_bw() + 
         ylab("") +
         xlab("") + 
         scale_fill_manual(name = "", 
                           values = c("red", "blue", "black")) 

print(ggOut)
ggsave(ggOut)
```

This code gives you this figure:
[image]

To change the legend, I followed [this guide](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/).