# Reorder factor levels as numbers after extracting from alphanumeric subset

Tags: r, sorting, subset, r-factor

I have a variant of a problem that [Reorder levels of a factor without changing order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-factor-without-changing-order-of-values) does not answer:
A variable in a dataset has mixed numbers and strings (I know that this is undesirable, but it's there), like `4 8 16 64 128 default`. When building the initial factor, the levels are kept in order (as found, which is sorted).

However when I build subsets (requiring to clean up stale levels), the levels are sorted as strings, like `128 16 4 64 8`, even if the subset only contains numeric levels.  This is bad when doing a `boxplot(var ~ factor)`.

Trying to use the solutions found in the question cited above (`factor(var, levels=sort(var)`), the levels ended with duplicates.

Most similar answers assume the levels are known, which is not true in my case.  How can I sort the factor so that the levels are sorted.

Example:

```
> a<-c(1,3,5,7,2)
> b<-c(4,8,16,32,"default")
> df<-data.frame(a, b)
> df$b<-factor(df$b)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  1 3 5 7 2
 $ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "16","32","4",..: 3 4 1 2 5
> ss<-subset(df, b != "default")
> factor(ss$b)
[1] 4  8  16 32
Levels: 16 32 4 8
> factor(ss$b,levels=sort(ss$b))
[1] 4  8  16 32
Levels: 16 32 4 8
ss$b<-factor(ss$b,levels=sort(ss$b))
boxplot(ss$a ~ ss$b)
```

Comment: I understand that you want a `factor` always but you don't know which levels you are going to have. The question is: whatever the new levels are, you want to order them first numerically and last `default` if it appears?

Comment: @R18: I'm undecided on what to do with the non-numeric values, but I want the numeric levels to be in order, i.e. not `16 32 4 8`, but `4 8 16 32`.

Comment: What about replacing `default`by a 0 ? This may avoid your problem.

Comment: @R18: Kind of, but it's more complicated: Depending on the value of another variable (not present in the example), the value `default` may represent different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Clunky but:

```
factor(ss$b,levels=sort(unique(as.numeric(as.character(ss$b)))))
```

Or perhaps more directly

```
ss <- droplevels(subset(df, b != "default"))
```

However, I question your assertion that

> When building the initial factor, the levels are kept in order (as found, which is sorted).

Seems to me they get sorted alphabetically?

Comment: You may be right with questioning my statement about sorting: Probably (I'm hacking on the script for two days) the initial version had no factors, but plain strings. An I found a similar solution to your proposal.

Comment: I'd like to point out the importance of `as.character()` in this solution: Without, the result is `Levels: 1 2 3 4`, but with it, it's `Levels: 4 8 16 32`.

Comment: For the proposal `ss <- droplevels(subset(df, b != "default"))`: The levels are not sorted after that: `ss$b` shows `Levels: 16 32 4 8`

Answer (score 1):

One real subset (the original data was too much to paste here) had a factor like this initially (including stale levels):

```
Levels: 0 128 16 256 32 4 512 64 8 deadline noop
```

Recomputing the factor (`factor(ss$tune.val)`), the levels were:

```
Levels: 128 16 256 32 4 512 64 8
```

This expression brought the desired result, but it looks a bit complicated to me:

```
factor(ss$tune.val, levels=sort(as.numeric(levels(factor(ss$tune.val)))))
```

(...)

```
Levels: 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512
```

Probably `unique(...)` is better than using `levels(factor(...))`.