# Reorder factor levels based on another factor

Tags: r

I have a data.frame `data` as follows.

```
data <- structure(list(fac1 = structure(c(6L, 16L, 4L, 14L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 
                                          2L, 15L, 10L, 11L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 13L, 12L), .Label = c("dd85", 
                                                                                               "ee01", "ee12", "ee78", "gs85", "jj45", "jj63", "qe89", "qq74", 
                                                                                               "tt23", "tt78", "vd41", "vd51", "ww77", "yy25", "yy85"), class = "factor"), 
                       fac2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                          3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("md", "av", "zr", "kj"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("fac1", 
                                                                                                                                  "fac2"), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")


levels(data$fac1)
levels(data$fac2)

data
   fac1 fac2
1  jj45   md
2  yy85   md
3  ee78   md
4  ww77   md
5  dd85   av
6  jj63   av
7  ee12   av
8  ee01   av
9  yy25   zr
10 tt23   zr
11 tt78   zr
12 qq74   zr
13 qe89   kj
14 gs85   kj
15 vd51   kj
16 vd41   kj

levels(data$fac1)
 [1] "dd85" "ee01" "ee12" "ee78" "gs85" "jj45" "jj63" "qe89" "qq74" "tt23" "tt78" "vd41" "vd51" "ww77" "yy25" "yy85"

levels(data$fac2)
[1] "md" "av" "zr" "kj"
```

How to reorder levels of `fac1` on the basis of `fac2` ?

I have tried `factor(data, levels=data[order(data$fac2),], ordered=TRUE)` according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-factor-without-changing-order-of-values), but it gives two levels.

```
factor(data, levels=data[order(data$fac2),], ordered=TRUE)
                                                    fac1                                                     fac2 
c(6, 16, 4, 14, 1, 7, 3, 2, 15, 10, 11, 9, 8, 5, 13, 12)        c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4) 
2 Levels: c(6, 16, 4, 14, 1, 7, 3, 2, 15, 10, 11, 9, 8, 5, 13, 12) < ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you are after, you can try ordering your data.frame and then passing the `fac1` as the (order of) levels.

```
data$fac1 <- factor(data$fac1, levels = data[order(data$fac2), "fac1"])
levels(data$fac1)

> data
   fac1 fac2
1  jj45   md
2  yy85   md
3  ee78   md
4  ww77   md
5  dd85   av
6  jj63   av
7  ee12   av
8  ee01   av
9  yy25   zr
10 tt23   zr
11 tt78   zr
12 qq74   zr
13 qe89   kj
14 gs85   kj
15 vd51   kj
16 vd41   kj
> levels(data$fac1)
 [1] "jj45" "yy85" "ee78" "ww77" "dd85" "jj63" "ee12" "ee01" "yy25"
[10] "tt23" "tt78" "qq74" "qe89" "gs85" "vd51" "vd41"
```