# ggplot2, reordering y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code:

```
library(readxl)
ttable <- read_excel("/Users/jhan/Downloads/test.xlsx")

library(ggplot2)  # Data visualization
library(dplyr)   # Data manipulation
library(gridExtra)

data.test <- ttable[,c('patient', 'zpati')]
data.test <- na.omit(data.test)
data.test <- data.test %>% group_by(patient) %>% summarise(zpati = sum(zpati), .groups = 'drop') %>% mutate(Procent = paste0(round((zpati/sum(zpati)*100),1), '%'))
data.test <- arrange(data.test,Procent)

pie3 = ggplot(data.test, aes(x="", y=Procent, fill=patient)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1)+ 
coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
geom_text(aes(label =Procent),size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#339ed1", "#c1d333", "#eaae33", "#87888a"), limits=c("GKV","Privat","BG/Unfall","Krankhaus")) +
 

labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, fill = NULL, title = "Patientenstruktur")+ theme_classic() + 
theme(axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          legend.direction = "vertical",
          legend.position = "bottom",
          legend.key.size = unit(0.25, "cm"),
          legend.key.width = unit(0.25,"cm"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 8),
                                     
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, color = "#339ed1")) 
pie3
```

This is my code, and I want to reorder my `y` values like the order of `fill("GKV","Privat","BG/Unfall","Krankhaus")`
my Y-variable ist not stored as a factor this ist numbers. and i export the data and make many number of Graphs. so the number would be changes according to the data.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder levels of a factor without changing order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375587/reorder-levels-of-a-factor-without-changing-order-of-values)

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure that your `y`-variable is stored as a factor, then you can set the levels (order) of these factors. It would look something like this:

```
pie3 = ggplot(data.test, aes(x="", y=factor(Procent,levels = c("GKV","Privat","BG/Unfall","Krankhaus"), fill=patient))
```

Comment: my Y-variable ist not stored as a factor this ist numbers. and i export the data and make many number of Graphs. so the number would be changes according to the data