# How can I swap the levels?

Tags: r, categorical-data, r-factor

I have the following code in R:

```
a <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes")
af <- as.factor(a)
```

Then

```
levels(af)
```

Returns

> [1] "No"  "Yes"

The problem is that `caret::confusionMatrix` considers the first factor as the positive one, if you don't pass a `positive` argument.

How can I swap the levels, so that the first one is "Yes"?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [Reorder levels of a factor without changing order of values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2375587/4752675)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `factor()` function:

```r
a <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes")
af <- factor(a, levels = c("Yes","No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forcats` library

```
library(forcats)
a <- c("No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes")
af <- as.factor(a)

af
[1] No  Yes No  Yes Yes
Levels: No Yes

fct_recode(af, Yes = "No", No = "Yes")
[1] Yes No  Yes No  No 
Levels: Yes No
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. You swapped all the values from Yes to No and viceversa. I want to swap the order after `Levels: `, I think. I don't want to physically change the values inside the variable

Comment: ok, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I think `caret::confusionMatrix` somehow considers the order in `Levels: `